# Setting the selected <option> inside a js loop which creates <select>s

Tags: javascript, html, loops, innerhtml

I need to dynamically change a select's selected option by changing .value. But the problem is that if I add something to the same html div after that it resets the selected option to the default. How do I make it remember which option was selected? Why does it even reset the previous selects?

I thought .innerHTML += means it adds html to the end of the element without changing what's already there...

I recreated the problem from my main js file so it's simpler. Basically we don't know which select's will be created and which options will be selected. That info comes from a database. So I can't just move the `document.getElementById("select"+i).value = "option"+i;` part after all the selects are created.
Outputs:

```js
function myFunction(a, b) {
inputs_div = document.getElementById("test_inputs");

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(i == a || i == b){

        inputs_div.innerHTML += '<select name="select_name" id="select' + i + '">' + 
                    '<option value="option0">option0</option>' +
                    '<option value="option1">option1</option>' +
                    '<option value="option2">option2</option>' +
                    '<option value="option3">option3</option>' +
                    '</select>';

        document.getElementById("select"+i).value = "option"+i;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test_inputs"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(1, 3)">run myFunction</button>
```

[image]

It should be option1, option3

Is there another way to select an  at the same time each  is created in a loop?

Comment: Adding to *innerHTML* first serialises the existing content, appends the new HTML, then parses it. Don't use *innerHTML*, add the option using *createElement*.

Comment: hmm didn't know about createElement. But it would be a ton of work to change everything now. I'm trying to somehow save all the select id's and option values in an array or object then set them after everything is created.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your user clicks the button, your `select` elements are completely deleted and recreated.  This behaviour happens because you are setting the `innerHTML` property to create them.  That is why the selected value resets every time - because you are seeing a brand new `select` element every time.

Comment: This would be a good answer if, in addition to stating the problem, it provided a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace *innerHTML* with DOM methods.

Regarding "*But it would be a ton of work to change everything now.*", the following took about 5 minutes based on the OP code.

```js
function myFunction(a, b) {
  inputs_div = document.getElementById("test_inputs");

  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if (i == a || i == b) {
    
      var sel = document.createElement('select');
      sel.name = "select_name";
      sel.id = 'select' + i;
      
      for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
        sel.appendChild(new Option('option' + j,'option' + j));
      }
      inputs_div.appendChild(sel);
      sel.selectedIndex = i;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test_inputs"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(1, 3)">run myFunction</button>
```